# How to connect a spare mobile phone camera to a display and power?

Tags: integrated-circuit, camera, iphone

I have an Apple iPhone front and rear cameras along with its A4 motherboard (yep, I disassembled it)
is it possible that I can get a live feed from these camera(s) to a display and connected to a power source? or maybe storing the recorded thing on a memory drive? 
I could not find the exact terms so the searches were not relevant. 
(images for reference attached)

[image: Camera pieces]

Comment: I suspect the only way you'll get anything usable out of these cameras is with a working iPhone.

Comment: @Finbarr so I won't be able to use these cameras somewhere else?

Comment: Unless you can get documentation on how to use the cameras, which I doubt, you would need to use specialised equipment and a lot of time and knowledge to figure that out for yourself, then design and program your own circuits to talk to them with no support available from anyone. Good luck!

Comment: @Finbarr so should I post another question on 'how to create a simple circuit sending camera footage to a display?' since your comment solved my question

Comment: That question would almost certainly be closed as too broad. What is it you're trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Finbarr all I just want to do is make my own camera circuit: I have a camera a display (both taken out from some old feature phone) and make my own circuit so that on closing the circuit the camera could send its footage to the Display in real-time

Comment: That is not a simple circuit. A smartphone will have a microprocessor, interface chips and lots of software in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After understanding @Finbarr 's comments:

> Unless you can get documentation on how to use the cameras, which I doubt, you would need to use specialised equipment and a lot of time and knowledge to figure that out for yourself, then design and program your own circuits to talk to them with no support available from anyone. Good luck!

And also that:

> A smartphone will have a microprocessor, interface chips and lots of software in the middle

It seems that my requirement cannot be fulfilled according to the way I wanted to.